# Python Module System - Import Sibling Subpackage

Tags: python, import, python-import

In Python, I want a file in a subpackage to import a sibling subpackage. Like so:

```
/proj
    __init__.py
    runner_main.py
    /subpackageA
        __init__.py
        helper.py
    /subpackageB
        __init__.py
        runnerB.py
```

In `runner_main.py`, I can call `import subpackageA` just fine.
However, calling `from . import subpackageA` fails with error

`ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessing' from '__main__'`

This isn't a problem, except I want to import `helper.py` from `runnerB`. Calling `from .. import subpackageA` fails with a similar error.

I don't want to put `/proj` on my system or Python path; I want it to work as a standalone package. How can I make this simple case work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
from subpackageA import classA, functionB, constantC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did this, and the error still occurs when I call `from .. import subpackageA` in `runnerB.py`. What gives?

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. I think I asked the same question before (can't find it), but consensus said that I can't do that, and if you want to use `subpackageA` in `runnerB.py`, then you must pull out `runnerB.py` into `/proj`.

Comment: Thanks @drum! My use case: I want to separate different people's work into different folders, like `temp_jared` and `temp_kyle`. Both these temp folders would reference a common utility module, for data preprocessing. How would you recommend structuring this?

Comment: I might have lied. But I need to know more about what's in your utility module. Do you have classes, functions, or a combination of both?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you run your code. You can import helper.py from runnerB. But If you run runnerB directly, it will gives you same error as you described. However If you run from any py file placed in the parent directory that import runnder module, it will work.